# POLLERR with netlink sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, netlink, poll-syscall

I am using netlink sockets for user space to kernel space communication.
In one of cases, recvmsg call fails with errno 105 which is ENOBUFS and then POLLERR is set on the fd.

After this there cannot be any more data flow between the user space and the kernel, so is there any way to know in the kernel that there has been something wrong with the fd. I mean is there any event generated or can I subscribe to anything in the kernel to let the know the current status.